# Manually binding data to Gridview

Tags: c#, gridview

I need to bind my SQL fields to my Gridview column. I did this a while ago and it worked great, but I forgot how to do this, so I let ASP.NET AutoGenerate the columns and it works, now I want to control the data binding, below is my code behind and my Gridview... any assistance will be appreciated.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Sitecore.Configuration.Settings.GetConnectionString("feedback"));
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from fb_results", conn);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(ds);
            GridView1.DataSource = ds;
            GridView1.DataBind();

            conn.Close();
        }
```

Gridview:

```
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>Feedback</title>
</head>
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="rpt_login" HeaderText="User Id" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="fb_url" HeaderText="URL___" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="fb_response" HeaderText="Answer: Did you find what you were looking for?" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="fb_noResponse" HeaderText="No Response or Ignore" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="fb_date" HeaderText="Date" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="fb_serviceCall" HeaderText="Prevented Service Call" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="fb_partsShipment" HeaderText="Prevented Parts Shipment" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="fb_warranty" HeaderText="Under Warranty" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="fb_cancel" HeaderText="Cancelled" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="fb_none" HeaderText="None of the Above" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: so what is your actual question?

Comment: I am sorry Russell... I want to turn off the AutoGenerateColumns, but I forgot how to code in my code behind to bind the columns in the Gridview.

Comment: just to confirm: you want JUST the BoundFields you have listed to show (as in the query has more columns than that, and they are all listing currently)?

Comment: yes true ... I am sure I need to do something to the ASPx page something with <% %> I just cannot remember or find examples. Plus, I am not sure what I need to do to BIND the fields in the code behind. thanks for any help you can offer.

Comment: I'm looking over my code that has a very similar example.  I had the same issue a while back.  Things to try: change `DataSet` to `DataTable`.  Also, I see that I got back too much info from my query, so I manually rebuilt the table to ONLY include the information I wanted.

Comment: Thank you Russel. I will look those over. Regards,

Comment: oh, also try adding `runat = "server"` in your `BoundField`s.  I'll post my code shortly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK.  So, regarding the comments:

This is my personal experience.  I had a SQL query that returned this:

```
|-----------------------------------------------|
|Column 1       |Column 2       |Column 3       |
|---------------|---------------|---------------|
|"c1foor1bar"   |"c2foor1bar"   |"c3foor1bar"   |
|"c1foor2bar"   |"c2foor2bar"   |"c3foor2bar"   |
|"c1foor3bar"   |"c2foor3bar"   |"c3foor3bar"   |
|---------------|---------------|---------------|
```

My aspx page looked like this:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" id="GridView1" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <asp:BoundField runat="server" DataField="strFirst"></asp:BoundField>
    <asp:BoundField runat="server" DataField="strLast"></asp:BoundField>
</asp:GridView>
```

And my pageload looked like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(<the info>);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM fb_results", conn);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(dt);
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();

    conn.Close();
}
```

There were two problems.  First, my columns weren't called the same.  I could easily change them, but they really did represent different data so I didn't want to do that.  Second, I was bringing in too much data.  My solution was to rebuild the table:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(<the info>);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM fb_results", conn);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(dt);

    DataTable newTable = createDataTableTemplate();
    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows) {
        DataRow newRow = newTable.NewRoW();

        newRow["strFirst"] = SomeOperation((String) dr["Column 1"]);
        newRow["strLast"] = SomeOtherOperation((String) dr["Column 2"]);

        newTable.Rows.Add (newRow);
    }

    GridView1.DataSource = newTable;
    GridView1.DataBind();

    conn.Close();
}

private DataTable createDataTableTemplate ()
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable("Table Title");

    DataColumn col1 = new DataColumn("strFirst");
    col1.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");

    DataColumn col2 = new DataColumn("strLast");
    col2.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");

    table.Columns.Add (col1);
    table.Columns.Add (col2);

    return table;
}
```

Please note: `DataSet` is not used, and all `BoundField`s have `runat="server"` in them.

Comment: wow... Russell, thank you for going to all of this trouble. I do appreciate it.

Comment: Hi Russell, I got this to work finally, so thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

templistClient = (from PTerm in objResponseLocal.GetPaymentTermResponseData.PaymentTerms
                                          where PTerm.OrganisationSupplierContractID == null
                                          select PTerm).ToList();

```
                    DataTable dt = grdPaymentTerms.ToDataTable(templistClient);
                    string strPaymentType = "";
                    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Paymenttermselectedpaymenttype", strPaymentType.GetType()));
                    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        dr["Paymenttermselectedpaymenttype"] = (Convert.ToInt32(dr["Paymenttermpaymenttype"]) == 1 ? "Final Payment" : "Deposit Payment");
                        dr["Paymenttermamount"] = (Convert.ToInt32(dr["Paymenttermpaymenttype"]) == 1 ? DBNull.Value : dr["Paymenttermamount"]);
                        dr["Type"] = (Convert.ToInt32(dr["Paymenttermpaymenttype"]) == 1 ? DBNull.Value : dr["Type"]);
                    }


                    grdPaymentTerms.DataBind(dt);
```

Comment: here Paymenttermselectedpaymenttype this is not strongly type Field