# Hiding Additional Attributes in a list of objects to be binded to a gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, gridview

I have a list of objects of type **user site load** that has many attributes , i want to hide some of these attributes because i do not want My grid view to show all of these.

How can i do it? I use **GridView.DataSource=MyListOfUserSiteLoadObjects;**

```
public partial class Create : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public List<Entity.UserSiteLoad> MyTempList = new List<Entity.UserSiteLoad>();
    public Entity.UserSiteLoad usl = new Entity.UserSiteLoad();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            Session["MyApplianceList"] = MyTempList;  
        }


    }

    protected void BtnAddNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<Entity.UserSiteLoad> LstUsl = (List<Entity.UserSiteLoad>)Session["MyApplianceList"];
        usl.Applianc = new Entity.Appliance();
        usl.Applianc.Name = DDLAppName.Text;
        usl.Quantity = Convert.ToInt32(QtyTB.Text);
        usl.DayTime = Convert.ToInt32(DayTymTB.Text);
        usl.BackUpTime = Convert.ToInt32(BackUpTymTB.Text);
        if (LstUsl.Count != 0)
        {
            for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < LstUsl.Count; rowIndex++)
            {
                string AppName = LstUsl[rowIndex].Applianc.Name;
                if (AppName == DDLAppName.Text)
                {
                    LstUsl.Remove(LstUsl[rowIndex]);
                }

            }
        }
        if (LstUsl.Count == 0 || LstUsl.Count > 0)
        {
            LstUsl.Add(usl);
        }



        AllItems.DataSource = LstUsl;
        AllItems.DataBind();
        AllItems.Visible = true;
        Response.Write("It has: " + AllItems.Attributes.Count);


    }
}
```

**2nd problem:** I want to add a column to my **GridView** named **"Appliance name"** and set its value to **usl.Applianc.Name** , **Applianc** is an aggregated object inside **user site load object**.

How is it possible?

Comment: Set AutogenerateColumns to false and explicitly specify all columns that must be shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should configure the `AutoGenerateColumns` property of the `<asp:GridView />` element to `false` and configure/bind the columns manually.

The following stack will give you an idea of how to do that:

[Manually binding data to Gridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17239942/manually-binding-data-to-gridview)

Obviously you should and can bind your own collections to the `DataSource` property.

I think your code-behind can stay as is and you only have to change some markup:

```
<asp:GridView ID="AllItems" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="PropA" HeaderText="Property A" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="PropB" HeaderText="Property B" />
        <!-- ... -->
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Thanks .. was a great help :)